# Python: While Statement = Statement Print associated Values

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, unique

In Python I currently have a Dictionary with a composite Key. In this dictionary there are multiple occurences of these keys. (The keys are comma-separated):

```
(A,B), (A,C), (A,B), (A,D), (C,A), (A,B), (C,A), (C,B), (C,B)
```

I already have something that totals the unique occurrences and counts the duplicates which gives me a print-out similar to this:

`(A,B)` with a count of `4`, `(A,C)` with a count of `2`, `(B,C)` with a count of `6`, etc.

I would like to know how to code a loop that would give me the following:

Print out the first occurance of the first part of the key and its associtated values and counts.

Name: A:

```
Type Count

B     4
C     2

Total  6
```

Name: B:

```
Type Count
A    3
B    2
C    3
Total 8
```

I know I need to create a loop where the `first statement = the first statement` and do the following, but have no real idea how to approach/code this.

Comment: How can you have a dictionary with the same key multiple times (`(A,B)` for example)?

Comment: Its from a list of list that basically comes from a huge text file. Where I had to look for certain Values and find the values associated with them. For multiple occurances of the dictionary I basically increased a value V by 1 for each occurance found. IF it didn't find that value it would create a new value and set it to 1. Sorry I was unclear. Meant to say that I basically increased the value for every duplicate found in the original list. Dictionary is all unique entries but the Value V for each entry represents the number of times found in original list.

Comment: @Alok: I think what the OP means is that he has a collection with `(A,B)`, etc. Then, he processes said collection into a dict using `collections.Counter`, presumably

Comment: Hmm, are the `(A,B)` style keys strings, or tuples? My answer might not be correct if they're really strings (though it would be pretty easy to modify the unpacking to grab the right substrings).

Comment: @Blackknght They are originally strings I think. I originally went through a file to find stuff that matched a pattern. I then pulled Two Values (The values in the key) From that each line that Matched what I was searching for. Its basically a file with IP Source and Destination Addresses and the associated protocols used.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly slow algorithm that'll get it done:

```
def convert(myDict):
    keys = myDict.keys()
    answer = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    for key in keys:
        for k in [k for k in keys if k.startswith(key[0])]:
            answer[key[0]][k[1]] = myDict[k]
    return answer
```

Ultimately, I think what you're after is a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Answer (score 0):

Its a little misleading to say that your dictionary has multiple values for a given key. Python doesn't allow that. Instead, what you have are keys that are tuples. You want to unpack those tuples and rebuild a nested dictionary.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
import collections

# rebuild data structure
nested = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in myDict.items():
    k1, k2 = k                # unpack key tuple
    nested[k1][k2] = v

# print out data in the desired format (with totals)
for k1, inner in nested.items():
    print("%s\tType\tCount" % k1)
    total = 0
    for k2, v in innner.items():
        print("\t%s\t%d" % (k2, v))
        total += v
    print("\tTotal\t%d" % total)
```